# How can I create a Visual Studio project template that shows up in the Web category?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, project-template, visual-studio-templates

I have created a project template that is installed via a VSIX extension.  This is working fine, but it only shows up in the Visual C# category.  I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to get it to show up in the Visual C# > Web category.

I have tried following the documentation for `ProjectType` and `ProjectSubType`, but when I specify `ProjectType=Web` and `ProjectSubType=CSharp`, it doesn't show up at all.

Looking at `.vstemplate` files in the `ProjectTemplatesCache` folder, I see examples of project templates that have `ProjectType=CSharp` and `ProjectSubType=Web`, but for me that only makes it show up in the root Visual C# category.  Doesn't show up in Visual C# > Web.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do this, create a new folder for custom item templates, let's say it's:

`c:\VS\Templates\Item`

Now on VS go to `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Projects and Solutions` and set the `User item templates location:` option to the folder above, hit OK.

You will notice that inside `c:\VS\Templates\Item` folder some folders will be created. What you have to do is to create a new `Web` folder inside the `Visual C#` folder that has been created automatically, therefore you'll have:

`c:\VS\Templates\Item\Visual C#\Web`

Drop the zip file with the item template there and the item will show up under the `Web` category when you are creating new items. You can create other categories as well just by creating new folders under `Visual C#` folder (or any other category folder for that matter).

Good luck.

Comment: What should be done when templates are packaged using VSIX?

Comment: @Dheeraj V.S.: In your VSIX project, create a sub folder under your ProjectTemplates or ItemTemplates folder and put the templates there. The sub folder name will be the category name.